# Как запустить на бесконечную работу телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Сделал телеграмм бота на python,решил попробовать залить на сервер.
Залил бота на сервер,запустил через файл,все работает,но как сделать что бы он работал без меня?Что бы я не запускал пк и тд.Я слышал это называется демон,но не нашел как его сделать и запустить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux здесь указано множество вариантов решения вашей задачи. я бы воспользовался вот этим: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643730/3744622

Comment: Я не понимаю как там обьясняют))У меня нет папок etc и тд

Comment: А какая у вас операционная система на сервере?

Comment: У меня стоит линукс,и простенький скрипт в 1 папке с 1 файлом main.py,а где я искал расписывают кучу не понятных вещей,вот я и решил сам спросить

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какой дистрибутив линукс?

Comment: 237-3ubuntu10.42 Если вы про это.Я просто сам на винде,сервер купил убунту.Не разбираюсь в этом,извиняюсь

Comment: Ответы по ссылкам выше подходят под вашу целевую систему (Ubuntu). Если по-русски пересказать ответ который я отметил, то нужно создать файл с настройками службы по примеру, а далее активировать и запустить службу. Возможно, у вас просто нет доступа к необходимым папкам на сервере. Без дополнительной информации трудно сказать, что именно вы делаете не так. Если вы арендуете сервер, то попросите администратора решить ваш вопрос. Или обратитесь к другой квалифицированной помощи, к примеру, на фрилансе.

Comment: Я сам написал скрипт,и хочу научиться размещать его на сервере.Сервер полностью в моих владениях я под root'ом.Все сделал,установил и перенес файлы на сервер,и сейчас только не понимаю как сделать что бы он работал постоянно самостоятельно без меня.Вот

Comment: Можете помочь сделать его?Я весь день сижу не понимаю как

Answer (score 2):

`systemd` – cистемный менеджер, демон инициализации других демонов в Linux. Проще говоря, `systemd` запустит бота и будет перезапускать его в случае падения.

Установим systemd:

```
apt-get install systemd
```

Создайте файл с именем, например `bot.service`, с таким содержанием:

```
[Unit]
Description=Telegram bot 'SuperPuperTelegramBot'
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/bot  # рабочая директория (каталог)
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/bot/bot.py  # путь до python и основного файла бота
# ExecStart=/opt/bot/bin/python /opt/bot/bot.py --serve-in-foreground  # если используется `venv` (`/opt/` как пример)
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

скопируйте файл `bot.service` в `/etc/systemd/system`

в консоли сервера:

- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl enable bot`  # где `bot` имя файла `bot.service`
- `systemctl start bot`
- `systemctl status bot`